# How to get data from mongo and store it in a variable in jade file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am using express.js for my application, i want to retrieve data from my mongodb and store it in a variable in my jade file, then i will use this variable to draw charts using dygraph.

```html
doctype html
html
   head
      title siddh
      link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
      script(type='text/javascript', src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/1.1.1/dygraph-combined.js')
   body
      #graphdiv(style="width:1000px; height=700px;")
      script(type='text/javascript').
          each doc, i in docs
```

. i am getting error in last line after each and it says "expecting newline or semicolon". And below is the javascript file for routing.

```js
exports.getData = function(req,res){

    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('collection');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('index1.jade',{docs:docs});
    });
}
```

I searched the internet but i am not getting any relevant data, and as a guide for node,mongo and express i am following this tutorial : cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/

Comment: @chridam, okay i will do that, thanks for the valuable comment

Comment: in ur exports.getData, just do a quick check if docs is not null , try to provide `console.log(docs)` and check error like `if(!e)` . After that in jade try to put docs directly like p #{docs}

Comment: @aishwat singh, from console i am getting something like this: -->
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 0.421 ms - -
[ { _id: 562dbf78a8c410c3ff306a3e,
    Date: '2015-10-24',
    TTFB: '845',
    loadTime: '5641' },
  { _id: 562dc10ca8c410c3ff306a3f,
    Date: '2015-10-21',
    TTFB: '800',
    loadTime: '8703' },
  { _id: 562dc10ca8c410c3ff306a40,
    Date: '2015-10-22',
    TTFB: '900',
    loadTime: '5758' } ] which means i am getting the data upto getData.js, now i need to render it in my jade file so that i can see charts from this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your docs either put `_id` as a string or remove that, that's an invalid json, test it at http://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidate, make it to string.

Then try this:

```
doctype html
html
   head
      title siddh
      link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
      script(type='text/javascript', src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/1.1.1/dygraph-combined.js')
   body
      #graphdiv(style="width:1000px; height=700px;")
      ul
         each val,i in docs
            li= val['_id']
            li= val['Date']
            li= val['TTFB']
```

And if you want it in graphdiv put JavaScript code as it is, you may test it here http://jade-lang.com/